# Hyperledger Fabric/Composer: Architecture for a multi-org network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm doing a POC that involves 4 types of entities. All of them will have different types of participants in the network. I have drafted out an architecture that needs validations and considerations that I might be missing out.

Architecture:

1. Created 4 Orgs on the Fabric. One for each of the entities.
2. The first org contains 1 CA, 1 Orderer, and 2 Peers.
3. The other three org contains 1 CA and 2 Peers.
4. All the Orgs will run on a different host machine.
5. All the Orgs are on the same channel.
6. Employ docker swarm to create an overlay and make these containers talk to each other.
7. Next, setup composer REST server on each of these machines, such that the PeerAdminCard and BusinessAdminCard are logically mapped to its own Org.
8. Use permissions.acl to control access to the participant's data.
9. A central server will get the requests from all these Org's client and pass it to the respective composer REST server.

Questions that I have pertaining this one:

1. Is this feasible to implement or am I missing any crucial point?
2. If we use docker swarm, then there will be a kind of master-slave communication. Does it break the essence of the blockchain?
3. There are different interactions happening between the clients and that is the purpose of using a central server. Is there other way to handle this without a central server?
4. Is the acl file enough to control access to the data? If someone has a physical access to the peer's couchdb, he'll be able to see the other participant's data?

Any guidance or references will be helpful.

Comment: 1. yes feasible. 2 can't see how it 'breaks the essence', will let others answer,  but you may find [this doc](https://dev.to/presto412/hyperledger-fabric-transitioning-from-development-to-production-4dch) useful 3. all depends on the purpose for 'interaction between clients' (ie blockchain or non-blockchain based) - would have thought the clients would interact with their own REST server (blockchain-based). 4. No - and do you mean Composer ACLs - See answer 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934312/how-your-data-is-safe-in-hyperledger-fabric-when-one-can-make-changes-to-couchdb)

Comment: Hi @PaulO'Mahony, for #3, there are interactions that non-blockchain based. Like sending notifications/messages to each other based on the blockchain's ledger data. And for #2, I tried using docker swarm for a single org and multiple peers today and it ran well. I'll be trying that for multiple orgs using the ref link you provided. Let's see how it goes. :) Thanks!